# How to properly close express servers making sure port are released

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this issue that especially on a Mac when I close a Node server "CTRL + Z" the server gets killed but the ports don't get released.

What is the proper way to close a server to make sure that the ports get closed so I can restart the server on the same port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key combination to kill a server (or any process in bash) is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> merely stops (pauses) the process and returns you to the current shell and can be resumed using `fg`.

Comment: Is there a way to kill a process to completely stop it?

Comment: CTRL+C does exactly that, unless if the process in question actively does not honor it.